# Error Linking shaders on NVidia vs Intel graphics

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, shader, glfw

I'm having an issue with my GLFW/C++ program where I am having an issue where the shaders will compile and link properly on an NVIDIA gpu but not on an intel integrated graphics card. I have been trying to fix this for hours for a school project but it seems to be getting nowhere. The shaders *will* compile properly on the intel side but it fails to link the shaders.

I know the shaders themselves are fine because they work in other projects I've done, it just fails in this specific one.

Here's some code for the shader linking

```
void ResourceManager::LoadMaterial(const std::string name, const char *prefix){

    // Load vertex program source code
    std::string filename = std::string(prefix) + std::string(VERTEX_PROGRAM_EXTENSION);
    std::string vp = LoadTextFile(filename.c_str());

    // Load fragment program source code
    filename = std::string(prefix) + std::string(FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_EXTENSION);
    std::string fp = LoadTextFile(filename.c_str());

    // Create a shader from the vertex program source code
    GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const char *source_vp = vp.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &source_vp, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    // Check if shader compiled successfully
    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status != GL_TRUE){
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, 512, NULL, buffer);
        throw(std::ios_base::failure(std::string("Error compiling vertex shader: ")+std::string(buffer)));
    }

    // Create a shader from the fragment program source code
    GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char *source_fp = fp.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &source_fp, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    // Check if shader compiled successfully
    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status != GL_TRUE){
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, 512, NULL, buffer);
        throw(std::ios_base::failure(std::string("Error compiling fragment shader: ")+std::string(buffer)));
    }

    // Create a shader program linking both vertex and fragment shaders
    // together
    GLuint sp = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(sp, vs);
    glAttachShader(sp, fs);
    glLinkProgram(sp);

    // Check if shaders were linked successfully
    glGetProgramiv(sp, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status != GL_TRUE){
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(sp, 512, NULL, buffer);
        throw(std::ios_base::failure(std::string("Error linking shaders: ")+std::string(buffer)));
    }

    // Delete memory used by shaders, since they were already compiled
    // and linked
    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    // Add a resource for the shader program
    AddResource(Material, name, sp, 0);
}
```

If you need other parts of the code I'll be happy to provide more but this is where it seems to fail on the intel side.

I really hope there's a dead simple fix to this that I have not found because this is a hair-pulling issue. Thanks in advance.

addendum #1: error code

```
Error linking shaders: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠: iostream stream error
```

Addendum #2 Cmake code

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

# Name of project
project(IlluminationDemo)

# Specify project files: header files and source files
set(HDRS
    asteroid.h camera.h game.h model_loader.h resource.h resource_manager.h scene_graph.h scene_node.h
)

set(SRCS
    asteroid.cpp camera.cpp game.cpp main.cpp resource.cpp resource_manager.cpp scene_graph.cpp scene_node.cpp material_fp.glsl material_vp.glsl metal_fp.glsl metal_vp.glsl plastic_fp.glsl plastic_vp.glsl textured_material_fp.glsl textured_material_vp.glsl three-term_shiny_blue_fp.glsl three-term_shiny_blue_vp.glsl three-term_textured_fp.glsl three-term_textured_vp.glsl three-term_toon_fp.glsl three-term_toon_vp.glsl
)

# Add path name to configuration file
configure_file(path_config.h.in path_config.h)

# Add executable based on the source files
add_executable(IlluminationDemo ${HDRS} ${SRCS})

# Require OpenGL library
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(IlluminationDemo ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})

# Other libraries needed
set(LIBRARY_PATH "" CACHE PATH "Folder with GLEW, GLFW, GLM, and SOIL libraries")
include_directories(${LIBRARY_PATH}/include)
if(NOT WIN32)
    find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY GLEW)
    find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY glfw)
    find_library(SOIL_LIBRARY SOIL)
elseif(WIN32)
    find_library(GLEW_LIBRARY glew32s HINTS ${LIBRARY_PATH}/lib)
    find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY glfw3 HINTS ${LIBRARY_PATH}/lib)
    find_library(SOIL_LIBRARY SOIL HINTS ${LIBRARY_PATH}/lib)
endif(NOT WIN32)
target_link_libraries(IlluminationDemo ${GLEW_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(IlluminationDemo ${GLFW_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(IlluminationDemo ${SOIL_LIBRARY})

# The rules here are specific to Windows Systems
if(WIN32)
    # Avoid ZERO_CHECK target in Visual Studio
    set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION TRUE)

    # This will use the proper libraries in debug mode in Visual Studio
    set_target_properties(IlluminationDemo PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX _d)
endif(WIN32)
```

Addendum #3 Shader code

Fragment Shader

```
// Illumination based on the traditional three-term model

#version 130

// Attributes passed from the vertex shader
in vec3 position_interp;
in vec3 normal_interp;
in vec3 light_pos[2];
in vec3 camera_pos;

// Material attributes (constants)
vec4 ambient_color = vec4(0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 diffuse_color = vec4(0.4, 0.8, 0.3, 1.0);
vec4 specular_color = vec4(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0);
float phong_exponent = 128.0;


void main() 
{
    // Blinn-Phong shading

    vec3 N, // Interpolated normal for fragment
         L, // Light-source direction
         V, // View direction
         H; // Half-way vector
    for(int i = 0; i < light_pos.length; i++){
    // Compute Lambertian lighting Id
    N = normalize(normal_interp);


    L = (light_pos[i] - position_interp);
    L = normalize(L);

    float Id = max(dot(N, L), 0.0);
    Id = round(Id*2.0) / 2.0;

    // Compute specular term for Blinn-Phong shading
    // V = (eye_position - position_interp);
    V = camera_pos - position_interp; // Eye position is (0, 0, 0) in view coordinates
    V = normalize(V);

    //H = 0.5*(V + L); // Halfway vector
    H = (V + L); // Halfway vector
    H = normalize(H);

    float spec_angle_cos = max(dot(N, H), 0.0);
    float Is = pow(spec_angle_cos, phong_exponent);
    Is = round(Is*2.0) / 2.0;

    if(dot(V,N) > mix(0.5, 0.5, max(0.0, dot(N,L)))){
    // Assign light to the fragment
    gl_FragColor += ambient_color + Id*diffuse_color + Is*specular_color;
    } else {

        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0) * (ambient_color + Id*diffuse_color + Is*specular_color);
    }
    }


    // For debug, we can display the different values
    //gl_FragColor = ambient_color;
    //gl_FragColor = diffuse_color;
    //gl_FragColor = specular_color;
    //gl_FragColor = color_interp;
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(N.xyz, 1.0);
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(L.xyz, 1.0);
    //gl_FragColor = vec4(V.xyz, 1.0);
}

// Illumination based on the traditional three-term model
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 130

// Vertex buffer
in vec3 vertex;
in vec3 normal;
in vec3 color;

// Uniform (global) buffer
uniform mat4 world_mat;
uniform mat4 view_mat;
uniform mat4 projection_mat;
uniform mat4 normal_mat;
uniform vec3 cameraPos;

// Attributes forwarded to the fragment shader
out vec3 position_interp;
out vec3 normal_interp;
out vec3 camera_pos;
out vec3 light_pos[2];

// Material attributes (constants)
//
// Could be loaded from a configuration file and also passed with the
// uniform buffer
vec3 light_position = vec3(-0.5, -0.5, 1.5);
vec3 light_position2 = vec3(4.0, -1.0, -1.0);


void main()
{
    camera_pos = cameraPos;
    // Transform vertex position
    gl_Position = projection_mat * view_mat * world_mat * vec4(vertex, 1.0);

    // Transform vertex position without including projection
    position_interp = vec3(view_mat * world_mat * vec4(vertex, 1.0));

    // Transform normal
    normal_interp = vec3(normal_mat * vec4(normal, 0.0));

    // Transform light position to align with view
    light_pos[0] = vec3(view_mat * vec4(light_position, 1.0));
    light_pos[1] = vec3(view_mat * vec4(light_position2, 1.0));
}
```

Addendum #4 Seem like the issue has to do with how the array light_pos[] is being passed between the shaders then the program freaks out when light_pos.length is called. Clarification on this would be appreciated.

Addendum #5 Graphics Adapters tested:
Intel:
HD 4600,
HD 5600,
HD 615
,,NVidia:
GTX 750 ti,
GTX 1080,
GTX 970m

Comment: Can you post the linker error?

Comment: The linker error message is of interest, but the shader code is of interest even more.

Comment: The error happens regardless of the shader code that's used, I have multiple shader programs and have tried others

Comment: You must use `glGetProgramInfoLog` to query the program object.

Comment: @Smcelrea The shader  is compiled by the graphics driver. The error tolerance varies between manufacturers. Probably there is one and the same issue in all your shader programs, which is accepted by NVIDIA but causes an error on Intel HD. So please show the error message and the shader code.

Comment: @Smcelrea I can reproduce this issue. It is related to the shader code, but I don't understand why. It compiles an linkes on my NVIDIA card, but fails to linke on my integrated Intel HD (more precisely `glLinkProgram` crashes). If I substitute `light_pos.length` by `2` it works. That confuses me, because `a.length` is clearly part of the [GLSL specification version 1.30](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf) (page 26).

Comment: omg that's it i found that too, it seems intel doesnt like finding the array's length

Comment: @Smcelrea You should extend your question and point out that issue. Maybe there is someone who can bring light into the dark.

Comment: Apply derhass's comment about `glGetProgramInfoLog` to get the right error info. Also, post your Intel card model, to see if your shaders hit some limitation.

Comment: @Smcelrea `length` is a function not a member, it has to be `light_pos.length()`

Comment: that.. seems like it would be a problem, thanks for the info

Comment: If you're not getting a valid error message from `glGetShaderInfoLog`, you might try passing a larger buffer (than 512). Even though it's supposed to give you a partial error, it may be a problem with the driver if the message size isn't large enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly specified in [GLSL specification version 1.30; 5.7 Structure and Array Operations; page 46](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf), `length` is a method and not a member and the correct syntax for to use is:

```
vec3 light_pos[2];

int l = light_pos.length();
```

Change `light_pos.length` by `light_pos.length()` to solve your issue.

Of course it is still surprising that the compiler doesn't generate an error message in this case.
In my case the NVIDIA driver accepted `light_pos.length` as if it were `light_pos.length()`.
Of course the Intel HD driver accepted `light_pos.length()`. Using `light_pos.length` didn't give any error message, but it causes an access violation at `glLinkProgram`.